# How to create an UIWindow with Vibrant background in MacCatalyst?

Tags: uiwindow, uivisualeffectview, mac-catalyst

We can create this effect easily with NSWindow and NSVisualEffectView in native mac app but how can we do it in app that was built for MacCatalyst?

[image]

of course setting alpha = 0 for UIWindow and add an UIVisualEffectView on it won't do the trick, it's not that simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `NSVisualEffectView` as a subview of `NSWindow.contentView`.

`NSWindow` isn't available for Mac Catalyst apps, so you have to create a macOS plugin as explained [here](https://www.highcaffeinecontent.com/blog/20190607-Beyond-the-Checkbox-with-Catalyst-and-AppKit), or use a library like [Dynamic](https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic) (Full disclosure: I'm the author) to do that without a plugin as follows:

```swift
let nsWindow = Dynamic.NSApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.hostWindowForUIWindow(view.window)

let visualEffectView = Dynamic.NSVisualEffectView(frame: NSZeroRect)
nsWindow.contentView.addSubview(visualEffectView, positioned: -1, relativeTo: nil)
visualEffectView.frame = nsWindow.contentView.bounds.asCGRect
visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = 18 /*NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable*/
```

The result is something like this:

[image]

---

EDIT: Don't forget to also make the controller's view transparent:

```swift
view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Comment: Dynamic is very interesting and promising. Thank you!